# Find unit vector perpendicular to x-z,x-y, and y-z plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm guessing that the unit vector perpendicular to the x-z plane is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

I'm guessing that the unit vector perpendicular to the x-y plane is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

I'm guessing that the unit vector perpendicular to the y-z plane is $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Am I correct?

Comment: None of these are unit vectors, and none of them are perpendicular to the plane you mention.

Comment: @T.Bongers How do I find the unit vector perpendicular to the planes?

Comment: Well, one way is the cross product. Another way is to think about which of the coordinate axes is perpendicular to each of the given planes.

Comment: Aren't two vectors perpendicular when their dot product is 0? Why is the cross product used?

Comment: Yes, vectors are perpendicular if their dot product is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, none of your suggestions are unit vectors since in all cases $|{\mathbf{v}}| = \sqrt{2}$.

You can check that

- a normal to $xz$-plane: $(0,1,0)$
- a normal to $xy$-plane: $(0,0,1)$
- a normal to $yz$-plane: $(1,0,0)$

by taking the dot with the relevant unit vectors in the $x,y,z$ directions.

Comment: How would you find the unit vector parallel to the xz-plane, xy-plane, and yz-plane?

Comment: For example, a unit vector parallel to $xz$-plane is just a unit vector in the $z$ direction or $x$ direction, e.g. $(0,0,1)$ and $(1,0,0)$ respectively. Can you do the others?